# page number in category

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I have a function which named `kriesi_pagination` this is a function for showing page numbers in php. I wrote the codes in function.php for my site. And I call this function in index.php for showing the page numbers in index. I use this code in index : `<?php kriesi_pagination(); ?>`

Now the question is what should I do if I want to show the page numbers in other places such as category. It just show the page numbers in home page of site not any other places.

I want to have page numbers for the categories like sports, musics, technology, .....

By the way I use wordpress cms for my website.

Please help me to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the query var value for paged to get the current page number:

```
function echo_page_number(){
    $page_number = isset($wp_query->query_vars["paged"])?
        $wp_query->query_vars["paged"] : // page number
        1; // not set, default to 1
    echo $page_number;
}
```

Comment: I want to call the function in category like I called the function in index.php

Comment: just wrap it in a function and add it to your category template, edited to reflect.

Comment: you can define the function in `functions.php`, and your category template is likely called `category.php`

Comment: Sorry I didn't find category template. I only have page template

Comment: If you do not have a category template file, you will need to create one in your theme: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates